# Python script to remove double quotes surrounding columns in a pipe delimited txt file

Tags: python, string

I have a few pipe delimited txt files. All the columns in each of those files are surrounded by double quotes. I want to remove those double quotes. The catch is one of the columns contain json data format so I dont want to remove double quotes in the json column. To give an example below are few lines of the txt file :

```
"Id"|"Name"|"KV_Pair"
"I03"|"Adam Smith"|"[{"objectives" : [  ]}]"
"I02"|"Jane Doe"|"[{"statementType":"Note","statementLabel":"Derm_Leave_Behinds_Disclaimer"}, {"statementType":"Note","sortOrder":2}]"
"I07"|"John Perry"|"[{"statementId":"SI098","statementType":"Note","sortOrder":1},{"statementId":"SI098","statementType":"Note1","sortOrder":2}]"
```

The final data should be :

```
Id|Name|KV_Pair
I03|Adam Smith|[{"objectives" : [  ]}]
I02|Jane Doe|[{"statementType":"Note","statementLabel":"Derm_Leave_Behinds_Disclaimer"}, {"statementType":"Note","sortOrder":2}]
I07|John Perry|[{"statementId":"SI098","statementType":"Note","sortOrder":1},{"statementId":"SI098","statementType":"Note1","sortOrder":2}]
```

I can use Python and powershell as two options to write script. I have been trying to write python script using the regex module but haven't quote figured out how to not remove the double quotes inside the json data. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why regex? If you use Python, just read the file as a CSV and do `x.strip('"')` for each column...

Comment: Using regex you can try to replace `\"(\[{.*?}]|[^\"]*)\"` with `\1` ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/o58Aaa/1))

Comment: It's pretty easy to just do what you said (already answered), but there are some gotchas. What if the quotes are allowing it to have pipes within a column? What if the actual value has quotes on the outside? Of course, if those cases don't actually happen, you can just strip things, but they were presumably there for a reason, in which case you have to actually parse, not just split and strip.

Comment: @KennyOstrom - Thanks for bringing that up. We already checked those 2 scenarios with the client and they assured us that those 2 scenarios wont creep up in the data. They have some sorta validation at their end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to read the file line-by-line, split the line by `|` and then strip `"` from each value. Then print the values (to stdout, you can redirect the stdout to another file afterwards):

```py
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if line == "":
            continue
        row = [v.strip('"') for v in line.split("|")]
        print(*row, sep="|")
```

Prints:

```
Id|Name|KV_Pair
I03|Adam Smith|[{"objectives" : [  ]}]
I02|Jane Doe|[{"statementType":"Note","statementLabel":"Derm_Leave_Behinds_Disclaimer"}, {"statementType":"Note","sortOrder":2}]
I07|John Perry|[{"statementId":"SI098","statementType":"Note","sortOrder":1},{"statementId":"SI098","statementType":"Note1","sortOrder":2}]
```